# JavaFX 2 cropping Shape objects

Tags: javafx-2, shapes

I need to create Shape objects, that have empty space in them. An example can be seen bellow: 
[image]

Currently the white space is another white rectangle, although I would actually want it to be empty - see behind the blue rectangle. Is that possible? I couldn't find any solutions on implementing this effect. 
This is my code:

```
package StackPaneTest;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


public class StackedPaneController extends Application
        implements Initializable {


    @FXML //  fx:id="panelBlock"
    private StackPane panelBlock; // Value injected by FXMLLoader
    @FXML
    private Rectangle body;
    @FXML
    private Rectangle redBox;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override // This method is called by the FXMLLoader when initialization is complete
    public void initialize(URL fxmlFileLocation, ResourceBundle resources) {
        Shape newShape = Shape.subtract(body, redBox);
        panelBlock.getChildren().add(0, newShape);
        panelBlock.getChildren().remove(body);

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("The test");
        Group root = new Group();

        try {
            root.getChildren().add((Node) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("StackedPaneBlock.fxml")));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }
}
```

And the FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="StackPaneTest.StackedPaneController">
  <children>
    <StackPane fx:id="panelBlock" layoutX="136.0" layoutY="74.0" prefHeight="126.0" prefWidth="185.0">
      <children>
        <Rectangle fx:id="body" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="DODGERBLUE" height="200.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="200.0" />
        <Rectangle fx:id="redBox" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="RED" height="48.99658203125" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="59.0" />
      </children>
    </StackPane>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

The output of my code is the following:
[image]

As you can see the subtracted shape is moved from the original position. I really need to get this working with FXML.

Comment: May be a poligon, where two sides are coupled (connected/joint)?

Comment: It should be straight forward to be done with Shape.subtract but I cant get it to work correctly.

Comment: It could be a bug in JFX, if it doesn't work. If you cannot deal with it, please, show a code, which you work with.

Comment: Seems, that substraction is done from position x=0, y=0, because rectangle in FXML has parameters (0,0,59,49). You will have to change x,y to change the substraction x0,y0-position. It is so, because red rectangle is aligned using other parameters, not x,y. (seems, layoutX, layoutY, or translateX, translateY)

Comment: Changing the X to layoutX value will make layoutX 0 and create proper subtraction effect. Do you know if setting layoutX to 0 could cause other complications? Thanks !

Comment: It is hard to say. May be, alignment: when some layout will think, that your rectangle 50,50,50,50, which is 50 width and height, starting from (50,50), will be estimated as 100x100 rectangle - that will lead to situation, when center will not be aligned, etc. But I cannot say, could it happen or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shape.subtract should work fine:

```
public class Test extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        final Rectangle outer = new Rectangle(0,0,200,200);
        final Rectangle inner = new Rectangle(50,50,100,100);

        final Shape result = Shape.subtract(outer, inner);
        result.setFill(Color.DODGERBLUE);

        final Group group = new Group();
        group.getChildren().add(result);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(group));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

The listing above produces the result you want. If it doesn't work you, please post the specific error message / a screenshot of the result.

Comment: Updated the question with my code. Your example works fine although it seems something must be done different for FXML.